# Why I am getting "Could not find store in the context of Connect(Speakers)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I get this error when I navigate to the component `Speakers`:

> **Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Speakers)". Either wrap the root component in a Provider, or pass a custom React context provider to Provider and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Speakers) in connect options.**

Even though I wrapped the root component in the store. See code below:

**Client.js** (root component)

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import FullPage from "./Components/common/FullPage";
import configureStore from "../redux/configureStore";

const store = configureStore(window.__STATE__);

const RootApp = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            <FullPage />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RootApp/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**Speaker.js** (the Speakers component)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SpeakersHeader from './SpeakersHeader';
import SpeakerList from './SpeakerList';
import connect from "react-redux/lib/connect/connect";
import {speakersFetchData} from "../../../redux/actions/speakers";
import configureStore from "../../../redux/configureStore";
import context from "react-router/modules/RouterContext";

class Speakers extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            /*Setting appData to an empty array, that way when the page renders, JSON stringfy can render an empty array instead of undefined*/
            appData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.speakersFetchData();
    }
    
    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <span><i>Loading...</i></span>
        }
        else if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <span><b>Failed to load data: {this.props.errorMessage}</b></span>
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <SpeakersHeader/>
                    <SpeakerList speakers={this.props.speakers} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

Speakers.propTypes = {};
Speakers.defaultProps = {};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        speakers: state.speakers.data,
        hasErrored: state.speakers.hasErrored,
        isLoading: state.speakers.isLoading,
        errorMessage: state.speakers.errorMessage
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { speakersFetchData })(Speakers)
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import axiosMiddleware from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import axios from "axios";

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    return createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, axiosMiddleware(axios.create({})))
    );
}
```

**reducers\speakers.js**

```
import {SPEAKER_LOAD, SPEAKER_LOAD_FAIL, SPEAKER_LOAD_SUCCESS} from "../actions/speakers";

export function speakers(state = {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
    hasErrored: false,
    errorMessage: ""
    }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case SPEAKER_LOAD: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: true,
                hasErrored: false
            });
        }
        //SPEAKER_LOAD_SUCCESS reducer
        case SPEAKER_LOAD_SUCCESS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                data: action.payload.data,
                isLoading: false,
                hasErrored: false
            });
        }
        //SPEAKER_LOAD_FAIL reducer
        case SPEAKER_LOAD_FAIL: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: false,
                hasErrored: true,
                errorMessage: action.error.message
            });
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**actions\speakers.js**

```
export const SPEAKER_LOAD = 'SPEAKER_LOAD';
export const SPEAKER_LOAD_SUCCESS = 'SPEAKER_LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const SPEAKER_LOAD_FAIL = 'SPEAKER_LOAD_FAIL';

export function speakersFetchData() {
    return {
        type: SPEAKER_LOAD,
        payload: {
            request:{
                url:'/data/speakers.json'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my **index.js** in `reducers`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {speakers} from './speakers';

export default combineReducers({
    speakers
});
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I don't understand why its can not find the `store`?
Any help is very appreciated.

**Edit:**

**FullPage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CodeCampMenu from './CodeCampMenu';
import PageTop from './PageTop';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Routes from '../../Routes';

class FullPage extends Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    }
    handler(val) {
        this.props.action();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PageTop>
                    <CodeCampMenu />
                </PageTop>
                <Routes  action={this.handler}  />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
FullPage.defaultProps = {};
export default FullPage;
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Components/home/Home";
import Speakers from "./Components/speakers/Speakers";
import Login from "./Components/common/Login";
import RouteNotFound from "./RouteNotFound";

class Routes extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    }
    handler() {
        this.props.action();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/speakers" component={Speakers}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route render={() => <RouteNotFound/>}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
Routes.propTypes = {};
Routes.defaultProps = {};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Can you show your FullPage component code?

Comment: component `class Speakers`  is not part of `FullPage` nor it is included in `RootApp` did you looked into that or is there any file missing would be great if you could share sandbox link

Comment: @techipank, see `Routes.js`

Comment: @techipank, sandbox link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-andras-b0x27?

Comment: I didn't saw any error but page is coming as empty and i don't need full code please correct it with minimal reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're right about the empty page (same here). When I check using Developer tools I find the error.

Comment: I solved the problem by passing the `store` to `connect()` in `Speakers.js`. This particularly store is just for `Speakers.js`.  And I removed it form the root component. At least, it works!